# A simple, one-knob volume control for KDE (kubuntu)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, volume-control, taskbar

What's the easiest way in KDE (Ubuntu 13.10) to have a simple, one-knob volume control for the default playback device? Right now there's kmix in the taskbar, which shows 3 volume sliders, *none* of which actually controls the volume of the default playback device. (I have to click "Mixer," look through the various playback devices and find "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo.")

In those rare cases where one needs to see every single playback device and stream, kmix is great, but for the other 99% of the time when I just want to turn down the music, a simple taskbar volume slider would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**KMix backends**

> What's the easiest way in KDE (Ubuntu 13.10) to have a simple,
>   one-knob volume control for the default playback device? ... "Built-in
>   Audio Analog Stereo.")

The KMix supports multiple backends: The Kmix blog: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/ and an older topic: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/winter-of-69-welcome-kmix-v4/

To get the "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo." option:

Right click the KMix and pick the 'Quit'

Add the PULSEAUDIO to the kmixrc as the backend. This can be done with the command:

```
kwriteconfig -file kmixrc -group Global -key Backends -type string PULSEAUDIO
```

Start the KMix again - Alt + F2 and the command kmix.

The KMix should now start with the pulseaudio backend:

[image]

Click the wrench icon

[image]

and only pick the 'Playback Devices'.

After this the KMix should offer only the 'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo' option. At here it does.

[image]

**Other mixers**

Veromix: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=116676 .
The Veromix is also in the Ubuntu repositories (plasma-widget-veromix).

ALSA Volume Control plasmoid : http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/?content=138990

**About kwriteconfig**

```
kwriteconfig --help
Usage: kwriteconfig [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] value 

Write KConfig entries - for use in shell scripts

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --file <file>             Use <file> instead of global config
  --group <group>           Group to look in. Use repeatedly for nested groups. [KDE]
  --key <key>               Key to look for
  --type <type>             Type of variable. Use "bool" for a boolean, otherwise it is treated as a string

Arguments:
  value                     The value to write. Mandatory, on a shell use '' for empty
```

Comment: This link solved problem for me: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/winter-of-69-welcome-kmix-v4/